# How to get the name of an instance to affect a tkinter label

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I'd like to be able to call a subroutine with an instance of a class passed to it and then use a string of the name of the instance to affect which tkinter label is updated.

I know this is an oddly specific and convoluted way of asking something that's probably quite simple but I'm bad at articulating what I need into google.

I'm making a fallout inspired game and I'd like to let the player choose an enemy to shoot at and update their health meter. So far I have all the maths behind the shooting subroutine down, I just don't know how to target the correct label widget at the end

```py
from tkinter import *
Root = Tk()

PlrWeapon = ["Pipe Revolver Rifle",6,5,0]

class Raider:
    Species = "Human"
    def __init__(self, Name, Level, MaxHealth, Health, Alive, Unique, Weapon, Armour):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Level = Level
        self.MaxHealth = MaxHealth
        self.Health = Health
        self.Alive = Alive
        self.Unique = Unique
        self.Weapon = Weapon
        self.Armour = Armour

def Shoot(self):
    Damage = 0
    for i in range(1,4):
        Difference = PlrWeapon[i] - self.Armour[i]
        if Difference >= 0:
            Damage = Damage + Difference
    self.Health = self.Health - Damage
    if self.Health <= 0:
        self.Alive = False

Enemy1 = Raider("Tessa",
                5,
                50,
                50,
                True,
                False,
                ["Pipe Pistol",3,2,0],
                ["Armourless",0,0,0])

Enemy2 = Raider("Bobby",
                5,
                50,
                50,
                True,
                False,
                ["Pipe Rifle",5,4,0],
                ["Leather",2,3,1])

Shoot(Enemy1)

Enemy1Name = Label(Root, text=Enemy1.Name)
Enemy1Name.grid(row=0, column=0)
Enemy1Health = Label(Root, text=Enemy1.Health)
Enemy1Health.grid(row=0, column=1)

Enemy2Name = Label(Root, text=Enemy2.Name)
Enemy2Name.grid(row=1, column=0)
Enemy2Health = Label(Root, text=Enemy2.Health)
Enemy2Health.grid(row=1, column=1)

Root.mainloop()
```

ideally at the end of the `Shoot()` routine there would be a part that acted like this

```py
def Shoot(self):
    Damage = 0
    for i in range(1,4):
        Difference = PlrWeapon[i] - self.Armour[i]
        if Difference >= 0:
            Damage = Damage + Difference
    self.Health = self.Health - Damage
    if self.Health <= 0:
        self.Alive = False

    ## start of wishful thinking ##

    str(self)+"Health".config(text=self.Health)
```

If you understand what I'm trying to communicate and have a solution I would really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: " I just don't know how to target the correct label widget at the end". Could you please explain what you mean by this? I Get everything else, just this statement is a little confusing. Also, what is fallout? Is it a game? I am a noob at gaming so forgive me for this question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to change the health label related to the `Raider` object passed to `Shoot` method.

Here is a solution which can work, but I am not sure if this is a suggested way of going as you have to be very careful.

```
def Shoot(self, win):
    Damage = 0
    for i in range(1,4):
        Difference = PlrWeapon[i] - self.Armour[i]
        if Difference >= 0:
            Damage = Damage + Difference
    self.Health = self.Health - Damage
    if self.Health <= 0:
        self.Alive = False
    win.nametowidget('.health{}'.format(self.Name)).config(text=self.Health)

Enemy1Name = Label(Root, text=Enemy1.Name, name='name'+Enemy1.Name)
Enemy1Name.grid(row=0, column=0)
Enemy1Health = Label(Root, text=Enemy1.Health, name='health'+Enemy1.Name)
Enemy1Health.grid(row=0, column=1)

Enemy2Name = Label(Root, text=Enemy2.Name, name='name'+Enemy2.Name)
Enemy2Name.grid(row=1, column=0)
Enemy2Health = Label(Root, text=Enemy2.Health, name='health'+Enemy2.Name)
Enemy2Health.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

The widgets are stored as a tree structure by tkinter, where your `Tk()` window is root represented by `.`. Then its children will be presented as `.unique_widget1_id` and children of widget1 like `.unique_widget1_id.unique_widget2_id`. By default, tkinter creates ids like `.140343920750152` which can be seen through `widget.__str__()` method.

But you can add user-defined names to widgets when creating them as shown in this solution(Please be sure that every widget have a unique name to avoid issues. If you create two widgets with same name then it will create only first widget and second one will be just a reference to the same widget). Then you can call `nametowidget()` method on any widget/window and provide relative/absolute path to get widget object(and perform operations on widget).

Let me know if you have questions.

PS: Widget name can not start from upper-case letter.